# List in C# throws error variable is a "field" but is used as a "type"

Tags: c#, list

Basicly, i need an list of objects sporocilo, but when i try to fill it the way someone explained on this forum, I get the error:e-posta.mainwindow.sporocila is a "field" but is used as a "type" and I don't know how am I supposed to solve this.

```
public class sporocilo
{
    string mapa;
    string posiljatelj;
    string prejemnik;
    string vsebina;

    public sporocilo(string m, string p, string pr, string vs)
    {
        mapa = m;
        posiljatelj = p;
        prejemnik = pr;
        vsebina = vs;
    }

    public string getPosiljatelj()
    {
        return posiljatelj;
    }
};

List<sporocilo> sporocila = new List<sporocilo>();
sporocila.add(("Prejeto","jan.mlinar@gmail.com","rok.sekalo@gmail.com","VSEBINA"));
```

I've put this code right after 
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
         {

I'd also like to know how to access the list later, for example with an array, i'd do a for statement which would loop through it, how can I loop through the list ?

Comment: You might want to turn the get method into a property: public string Posiljatelj { get { return posiljatelj; } }

Comment: You have your basic answer, but a couple of things that might help you out (and help others read your code): (1) Try and think of different names for your class (sporocilo) and a list of those classes. Something like `SporociloCollection` is clearer. (2) think of better names for your constructor parameters. `m`, `p`,`pr` and `vs` don't help you remember what their purpose is.

Comment: Well, it's the only 4 parameters i need, and i prolly won't use them anywhere else but in the constructor, and they are kidnof clear to me while it's my native language. Anyway, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this has to be in the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx)

Second the Add method is with a capital A.

Yeah and third

```
sporocila.Add(new sporocilo("Prejeto","jan.mlinar@gmail.com","rok.sekalo@gmail.com","VSEBINA"))
```

Comment: Instead of posting a link it's better to copy&paste relevant bits if it's really needed

Comment: Would you mind letting me know how to loop through the list ?

Comment: @user3080261:  `foreach(var item in sporocila){}`

Answer (score 4):

Should be

```
  List<sporocilo> sporocila = new List<sporocilo>(); 
  sporocila.Add(new sporocilo("Prejeto","jan.mlinar@gmail.com","rok.sekalo@gmail.com","VSEBINA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your class `public class sporocilo` into a separate file.

Put the rest of your code e.g. in the constructor of MainWindow, like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
  public MainWindow()
  {
    List<sporocilo> sporocila = new List<sporocilo>();
    sporocila.Add(new sporocilo("Prejeto","jan.mlinar@gmail.com","rok.sekalo@gmail.com","VSEBINA")
  }
}
```

Comment: -1. That's not the problem at all. The issue is that he's adding strings to his list, rather than instances of his custom object.

Comment: No, this is the issue as reported by the compiler because the List declaration is at the class level and the call to the Add method is outside. Then there's another problem with the usage of the Add method but this answer is, in fact, valid.

Comment: Exactly, I solved part of the issue. I forgot the ctor though, stop bashing me.

Comment: Haha. Downvote removed. I think everyone presumed he wasn't trying to run it as a single sequential file. Perils of answering questions to which there are multiple basic problems :)

Comment: You probably want the list declaration to be outside of the constructor since he wants to access it later. See last part of post.